# `How to get the relative position of the sub item contained in 'activeselection' in fabricjs'?

Tags: fabricjs, fabricjs2

Fabricjs version: v4.6.0

[image]

```js
const selection = new fabric.ActiveSelection(objs, { canvas })
const childs = selection.getObjects()
console.log('first child position:', childs[0].left, childs[1].top) // -120, -243.5
```

The 'left' or 'top' I get is negative, which seems to be wrong

Comment: Do you have the code that created these elements?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.